# Retrieving the CURL authentication server-side

Tags: php, curl

I'm setting a CURL authentication, using CURLOPT_USERPWD:

curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $login); // Authenticate

How can I access this value server-side, so I can check it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you're talking of HTTP Basic Authorization, PHP store it credentials in the `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` and `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PASS']`

Or you can use web-server config to check this password.

Comment: Note: If the server mode is CGI, you can refer here: http://www.besthostratings.com/articles/http-auth-php-cgi.html

Answer (score 2):

`$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PASS']` should be `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']`